# Lists and GUI - dynamically

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I have questions about working with lists,

I write my da ta with composits blocks in GUI, but now when i dispose one of the block i need to make that block that is below the block that i dispose dynamically change position..Now if i have 4 blocks, and I'm deleting second block, I want to make that block 3 and 4 come on the position 2 and 3 because when i delete block 2 on his position is empty space..

```
    TabItem tbtmStudent = new TabItem(tabFolder_1, SWT.NONE);
tbtmStudent.setText("Student");

ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite_1 = new ScrolledComposite(tabFolder_1, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
scrolledComposite_1.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
    public void mouseScrolled(MouseEvent e) {

        scrolledComposite.setFocus();
    }   
});

tbtmStudent.setControl(scrolledComposite_1);
scrolledComposite_1.setExpandHorizontal(true);
scrolledComposite_1.setExpandVertical(true);


List<STUDENT> allSTUDENTNodes = currentData.getStudentNodes();

Composite studentChild = new Composite(scrolledComposite_1, SWT.NONE);
studentChild.setLayout(new GridLayout());

for(STUDENT studentNode: allSTUDENTNodes){

    new STUDENTNode(studentChild, SWT.NONE, studentNode);

    Composite achivementsChild = new Composite(scrolledComposite_1, SWT.DEFAULT);
    achivementsChild.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    for(Achivements achivementsNode: studentNode.getAchivements()){
        new AchivementsNode(mscbcChild, SWT.NONE, achivementsNode);
    }
}
scrolledComposite_1.setContent(studentChild);
scrolledComposite_1.setMinSize(studentChild.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but I think what you need is [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html). You can take a look at [this guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) to figure out how to use lists.

Comment: Side note on code quality: for me, your code is doing way to many things in one spot. A method should do **one** thing, not 5 or 10. It should use **one** layer of abstraction; not several. Besides: variable names ending with _1, _2 ... and so on ... sometimes indicate that one might consider using arrays instead of specially named variables ...

Comment: I just want to make that when i dispose one of the blocks position of the block is changed beacuse when you dispose block and don't change position on the place where block was is empty space..

Answer (score 0):

If you `remove` an element from a list, then the elements later in the list will have their position reduced by one. Try this way:

```
allSTUDENTNodes.remove(2);
```

and then check the second and third element with `allSTUDENTNodes.get(2)` and `allSTUDENTNodes.get(3)`, respectively.

See the description in the docs:

> E remove(int index)
>
> Removes the element at the specified position in this list (optional
>   operation). **Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one
>   from their indices).** Returns the element that was removed from the
>   list.
>
> Parameters:
>       index - the index of the element to be removed Returns:
>       the element previously at the specified position Throws:
>       UnsupportedOperationException - if the remove operation is not supported by this list
>       IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size())

and

> boolean remove(Object o)
>
> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list,
>   if it is present (optional operation). If this list does not contain
>   the element, it is unchanged. More formally, removes the element with
>   the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null :
>   o.equals(get(i))) (if such an element exists). Returns true if this
>   list contained the specified element (or equivalently, if this list
>   changed as a result of the call).
>
> Specified by:
>       remove in interface Collection Parameters:
>       o - element to be removed from this list, if present Returns:
>       true if this list contained the specified element Throws:
>       ClassCastException - if the type of the specified element is incompatible with this list (optional)
>       NullPointerException - if the specified element is null and this list does not permit null elements (optional)
>       UnsupportedOperationException - if the remove operation is not supported by this list

The second variance calls the first one, but searches for the element first. So, whenever you call `remove`, it will shift subsequent elements to the left, just as you wanted. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)